# How to display certain photos based on dropdown menu in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

In my job, (I'm just a student worker, nothing major), my boss wants me to figure out a way to display photos on our website. Here's the catch:

My questions are:

1. is there a better way to go about this? Am I complicating things? 
   (I considered using a backend database to store the URLs so it would be easy to add/remove from the dropdown menu options, but that's proved to be difficult to figure out)
2. if this is a good way, how do I make it work on mobile?

```
 $(function() {

  // WHEN THE BUILDING CHANGES
  $('#buildings').on('change', function() {

    // set val equal to BUILDING VALUE
    var val = $(this).val();
    // set room = ROOMS
    var room = $('#room');

    // if it's the BSB, show the wings - else hide them.
    if (val == "BSB") {
      $('#wings').show();

      // Change the room numbers based on selected Wing
      $('#wings').on('change', function() {
        val = $(this).val();

        room.find('option').not(':first').hide();
        $('option', room).filter(function() {
          if ($(this).attr('data-group') == val) {
            $(this).show();
          }
        });
        room.val(0);
      });
      $('#wings').trigger('change');

      // must not be the BSB
    } else {
      $('#wings').hide();

      // select room based on Building
      room.find('option').not(':first').hide();
      $('option', room).filter(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-group') == val) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      });
      room.val(0);
    }

  });
  $('#buildings').trigger('change');
});

function setImage(select){
    var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}


function resetImage(){
    var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
  image.src = "";
}
```

[CLICK HERE FOR THE JSFIDDLE OF MY CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/vhysnygb/)